# Converting Numpy array to Dataframe using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am struggling to convert a NumPy array to a data frame.
This has been imported from a CSV file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5DWh.png)

I have tried codes like

```
carsdf = pd.DataFrame(newdf=newdf[1:,1:],
                         index=newdf[1:,0],
columns=newdf[0,1:])
```

however, get a type error.

I have tried reshaping

print(mydata.reshape((213, 26)))

and get value errors
Now am flustered as I know how to rectify typos, errors, capitalize and fetch data and all the other stuff only my coding is pretty raw and am stuck with this as it is the beginning of the assignment.
would appreciate all advice.

Comment: `sep` defines the character used to separate fields (the delimiter). From the look of your file it should be `sep='#'`, not a comma.

Comment: You have separate the file by `#` not by `,` you have to change that!

Comment: Thank you @ALollz.   You helped me fixed my issue now everything works fine. Much appreciated mate.